# What is the origin of the "-ingen" suffix in town names in Europe, particularly Germany?

Tags: etymology, standard-german, place-name, proper-noun

Quite a few villages, towns and cities have their name ending in -ingen: Sigmaringen, Singen, Villingen-Schwenningen (combo), Donaueschingen, Memmingen, Tübingen, Überlingen, Uhldingen. I could go on and on.

What is the origin and the meaning of this suffix?

From experience, I think this is prevalent in Baden-Württemberg. Could it be a Swabian thing?

Comment: *From experience, I think this is prevalent in Baden-Württemberg* – Well, there’s *Göttingen.*

Comment: Indeed, and I'm sure there must be other exceptions ( the northernmost I found was Heeslingen) but it is very frequent in the south. No idea what to make of this information, though.
Quite a few of the Viennese districts also end in -ing, that might be related.

Comment: Or, RLP: Bingen, BAY: Schwabing, Pasing, Altötting, Germering, Herrsching, Memmingen, CH: Peking

Comment: Peking (CN) ist in die Schweiz (CH) umgezogen?

Comment: Some NL cities: Groningen, Scheveningen, Vlaardingen, Vlissingen...

Comment: 京 (mandarin jīng, cantonese ging) means 'capital'. Not related... unless the Chinese garden in Zürich is the proof of the influence of upper Germanic on the Chinese culture or vice versa

Comment: Just wanted to mention Thüringen :-)

Comment: Bingen, Solingen, Willingen ...

Comment: @drolex: Nicht zu vergessen Oberösterreich: Fucking.

Comment: I was born in the US, but some of my ancestors came from Erpfingen in southwestern Germany. In looking at the map, I noticed that so many of the names of the cities/towns in that area have the suffix "ingen" attached. This suffix does seem to be more prevalent in that area of Germany. Thanks for the info. I hope some day to be able to travel to Erpfingen. From the air (Google Earth) the area seems so clean, so orderly, which doesn't surprise me, I suppose. I am proud of my German ancestral link.

Comment: As is well known, *Sphingen* is the plural of *Sphinx.* Analogously, *Villingen-Schwenningen* is the plural of *Villinx-Schwenninx,* etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The suffix "-ingen" describes the affilation to a leader or a person in general. So in Sigmaringen lived the relatives of Sigmar.

This is not a swabian thing, as you can find many town names with this suffix (even in Europe). It comes from the transmigration when regions were settled by germanics.

The origin of this suffix is old high german or germanic. It comes from "ing" or "jung" and means child.

Sources (in German):

- [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/-ing)
- [SWR](http://www.swr.de/blog/1000antworten/antwort/3015/warum-enden-im-schwabischen-so-viele-ortsnamen-auf-%E2%80%9E-ingen%E2%80%9C/)

Comment: To mention the source: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/-ing

Comment: and [swr.de](http://www.swr.de/blog/1000antworten/antwort/3015/warum-enden-im-schwabischen-so-viele-ortsnamen-auf-%E2%80%9E-ingen%E2%80%9C/).

Answer (score 8):

-ingen (or -ing,-ung, -engo and others) denotes affiliation to a person, place or geographic landmark. It is common in names of persons and places in many European regions where Germanic languages had or have influence on local culture.

Some examples include:

- Göttingen, meaning 'inhabitants close to the river Guta'
- Tübingen, meaning 'founded by Tuwo'
- Reading, meaning ''Reada's People' (probably)

Other places can be found in Sweden, Denmark, the Netherlands', Switzerland, northern Italy and other regions.

Comment: How does that contradict the other answer? Is it the fact that it doesn't only apply to people but also places?
Nice examples, that's interesting.

Comment: @drolex you are right, I will delete the first comment

Answer (score 2):

The accepted and most-voted answer refuses the regional aspect of the suffix *-ingen*. It  had been used to name places wherever Germanic peoples settled including Scandinavia and Great Britain and generally refers to a person (see also Merovingian, Carolingian). Still, the OP is right in suggesting that it is much more prevalent in Southern Germany: Among the many possible ways to name places some have been more popular in certain regions and periods of time.

In particular, the ending *-ingen* is typical for the Alemannic colonization in the 6th and 7th century ([Oltner Tagblatt](https://www.oltnertagblatt.ch/solothurn/olten/was-die-endung-eines-ortsnamen-ueber-den-ort-aussagt-130038234)) and also for the Bavarian settlement.

[image: Image by [Moritz Stefaner (2016)](https://github.com/moritzstefaner/ach-ingen-zell)]

The visualization is taken from a [site](http://truth-and-beauty.net/experiments/ach-ingen-zell/) by Moritz Stefaner which shows the geographic distribution of different endings within Germany (results also accessible via a [Stern online "article"](https://www.stern.de/panorama/gesellschaft/endungen-von-ortsnamen-auf-deutschlandkarten---hier-liegen-die-achs--ingens-und-zells-6632568.html#mg-1_1590133314066)).
Some of the more notable:

- *-ach*: Mostly in Frankish settlement areas in the Palatinate and Southern Hesse, but also in Saxony and Baden. Less frequently found in Bavaria and other parts of Southern Germany. Unusual in Northern Germany.
- *-au*: Mostly in the Western part of the former GDR along a belt between Lübeck and Zwickau. This ending may either be Slavic (*-ow*, *-ov*,...) or Germanic. In the latter case the name indicates the presence of a meadow.
- *-bach*: (indicating the presence of a creek) The distribution is similar to *-ach* but doesn't extend eastward into Thuringia and Saxony.
- *-berg*: (indicating the presence of a mountain or hill) Places with this suffix can be found almost everywhere in Germany.
- *-bruch*: (indicating that there had been a swamp) Mostly in old Saxon settlement areas in Westfalia and Lower Saxony.
- *-dorf*: (village) Mostly in Eastern Germany. Settlements of this type were founded during the [Ostsiedlung](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostsiedlung).
- *-feld*: (field) Almost everywhere in Germany, but rare in most parts of Southern Germany.
- *-itz*: Very frequent in Eastern Germany, but absent in Western Germany as the suffix is of Slavic origin.

Comment: Conflating *-ingen* and *-ing* into one map is … wow. In Southern Bavaria, there’s a relatively sharp border between the *-ingens* (on the Swabian side) and the *-ings* on the Bavarian side.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard that Swiss German attests to same phenomenon with the etymologically related GN ending -ikon (e.g., Dietlikon, Pfäffikon, Zollikon).

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. Do you think you can add a source where you "heard that"? Because I've heard many things - at least I believe I do - yet there is not much checking possible. So please add a source for your "claims".

Answer (score -1):

The suffix ingen is taken from the ancient Allemani  language, and means “the people from.”  The Allemani were an old Germanic tribe.

Comment: -1 needs citing (other than English wikipedia) and anyway is wrong. -ingen has counterparts in French (e.g. -ange) and Italien as well.